# AI faces Weird Direction when following a waypoint UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

My problem is that whenever it tries to move towards the current waypoint, it faces weird directions and does not follow the path completely.

```
IEnumerator FollowPath() {
    Vector3 currentWaypoint = path[0];

    while (true) {
        //transform.LookAt (currentWaypoint);
        if (transform.position == currentWaypoint) {

            PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position,target.position,OnPathFound);
            targetIndex=0;
            targetIndex ++;
            //Debug.Log(currentWaypoint);

            if (targetIndex >= path.Length) {
                targetIndex =0;
                path = new Vector3[0];
                //yield break;
            }
            currentWaypoint = path[targetIndex];
        }

        transform.LookAt (currentWaypoint);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,currentWaypoint,speed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Currently using a* pathfinding. Complete source code is found here: https://github.com/SebLague/Pathfinding

When it reaches the current waypoint, it randomly changes its direction or randomly faces direction and does not go through the next waypoint. [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOnle.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this part in the code, `targetIndex` will always evaluate to `1`

```
targetIndex=0;
targetIndex ++;
```

So basically, it will never go further than the first waypoint.

Also, i would recommend that instead of

```
if (transform.position == currentWaypoint)
```

You would do this instead:

```
float threshold = 0.1f;                // Adjust to your preference
if ((currentWaypoint - transform.position).sqrMagnitude < threshold)
```

This is because i think `MoveTowards` can possibly overshoot or not reach exactly the target vector and will hand around and change direction drastically when hovering over the target vector.

Comment: i forgot to tell that it does go to the other waypoint when there is no direction, or the position is static. but when i added direction to where he looks at too, it faces weird direction for about 10seconds then goes to the next waypoint or sometimes does not go to the next waypoint because he is STUCKED looking at that currentwaypoint.

Comment: get rid of `targetIndex=0;`

Comment: i did try your suggestion, but it still faces weird direction after reaching the waypoint. Though i have somehow got where the error comes from. It comes from the Animation and this line of code "transform.LookAt (currentWaypoint);". I did try to remove the animation and somehow it goes to the next waypoint. How can i fix this? the animation has a static run only. so it has no idle or anything, only Run animation.

Comment: I will surely try your suggestion. Thanks for the help! will update you later if it works.

Comment: Works great! Thanks. That saved me! 